# How do you test that a list gets ordered in a unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a method that I need to test that takes an `IEnumerable<T>`. It is required that this method performs a set of operations against this enumerable in a specific order.

(I have simplified the function for brevity's sake.)

```
public void TestMe(IEnumerable<IObject> objects) {
  foreach (var obj in objects.OrderBy(x => x.Priority)) {
    DoSomethingWithObject(obj);
    DoSomethingElseWithObject(obj);
  }
}

private DoSomethingWithObject(IObject obj) { }
private DoSomethingElseWithObject(IObject obj) { }
```

How do I write a test that makes sure the operations are performed in the correct order when `DoSomethingWithObject` and `DoSomethingElseWithObject` are private?

Comment: I might be missing something, but why does this order the list?  Since the object is passed into those methods, it is unknown factor to those methods, thus ordering makes no difference (with the code you've provided).

Comment: There's some kind of effect *somewhere*, so isolate that and test. One might assume it does something to IObject, so mock IObject and validate against it that it is used the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the result of `TestMe`? What will the caller see when `TestMe` is invoked? Why would he call this method in first place? **What is he trying to accomplish?**

Those are the questions you might want to answer with unit tests. Implementation details (like private methods) are irrelevant. What is important is *how the outside world perceives your method*.

If your method changes some state of `IObject`, test that those changes were **in fact** made. It's as simple as that.